# Why can't nuget restore packages on mapped network drive?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nuget, network-drive

I have a Xamarin project that is sitting on my VM hosts (ArchLinux) file system. The Windows 10 guest has a mapped drive to the hosts file share. I can open the Visual Studio solution just fine and I am able to create new files in the solution without error.

However, when I build / run the project I get the following error.

> The command ""Z:\source\mycomp\myproj\.nuget\NuGet.exe" install "Z:\source\mycomp\myproj\test\packages.config" -source ""  -NonInteractive -RequireConsent -solutionDir "Z:\source\mycomp\myproj\ "" exited with code 5. Please verify that you have sufficient rights to run this command.

Again on the file share I have full control to the file system. I can create files / folders with no problems. I was thinking maybe it's a trust issue so I followed this superuser [link](https://superuser.com/questions/44503/how-do-i-tell-windows-7-to-trust-a-particular-network-location) and added the file share to my trusted intranet sites. That still didn't fix the issue. Has anyone come across this in the past?

**EDIT**

Here is an image as requested:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Crystal ball says that the executable has the "came from the Internet, not trusted" attribute.  Use Explorer, right-click nuget.exe and click Unblock.

Comment: Ha, I wish it was that simple

Comment: Well, you do make it unnecessarily difficult by not showing us the access rights to the file for the current user.  Use superuser.com if you have no idea what that means.